# Function name in cmdlet

Tags: string, function, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I try to use my function in with set-acl cmdlet but it does work correctly, my function is recognized as a simple "string".

```
$acl = Get-Acl C:\MSI -Verbose
$acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($True, $False) 
$rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule ("Get-GroupName -SID 'S-1-1-0'","FullControl", "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow") -Verbose 
$acl.AddAccessRule($rule) 
$rule = New-ObjectSystem.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("Get-GroupName -SID 'S-1-5-32-544'","Readandexecute", "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow") -Verbose 
$acl.AddAccessRule($rule) 
Set-Acl C:\MSI $acl
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's recognized as a string, because you wrote it as a string. Everything inside quotes (" or ') are strings.

If your function returns a string value, then you could use it like this:

```
$acl = Get-Acl C:\MSI -Verbose
$acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($True, $False) 
$rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule ((Get-GroupName -SID 'S-1-1-0'),"FullControl", "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow") -Verbose 
$acl.AddAccessRule($rule) 
$rule = New-ObjectSystem.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule((Get-GroupName -SID 'S-1-5-32-544'),"Readandexecute", "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow") -Verbose 
$acl.AddAccessRule($rule) 
Set-Acl C:\MSI $acl
```